# How to delete text in parentheses with SQL query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, parentheses

I have a table that I want to normalize. One column  contains redundant information in parentheses. So, I have cells in this column with the following structure:

**text (texttodelete)**

**text**

**text (text) text (texttodelete)**

**text (texttodelete**

**text (text) text (text) (texttodelete) text**

I want to delete  (texttodelete) ( texttodelete and its parentheses). I'm using msaccess.

Comment: We must assume that the text to delete will not always be in the last parentheses? for example: is **text (text) text (text) (texttodelete) text (text)** possible?

Comment: no, I didnt find pattern **text (text) text (text) (texttodelete) text (text)** , so it is alwasys in last parentheses ( look, in some variant they are not closed at right side)

Comment: delete might not be the correct term.. should be Replace...https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/replace.php

Comment: Practically, if you have no need to automate this in the future, and if you do it only once, I would try to put it in Excel's text to column function. At least, you will be able to normalize your table in an easier way. However, this does not use a SQL query. To use a SQL query, I'm sure (unless someone show me an other way) that you will have to create a UDF, taking as input your cell's content and returning your text without **texttodelete**.